# Comparing arrays of different size

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, comparison, type-safety

I am implementing my own `boost::array` variant for fun and education, and I was just wondering: should comparing two arrays of different size yield false, or should it be a type error?

```
array<int, 3> a = {1, 2, 3};
array<int, 5> b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

a == b   // <--- false or type error?
```

Comment: Yes, it should. Honestly, there's no one answer to this that always makes sense -- sometimes you want a lexical comparison, other times it's a clear logical error.

Comment: @Jerry: Lexical comparison would imply a third possible result: *true*. I do *not* consider two arrays of different size equal, however.

Comment: If it's for fun and education. Do both.

Comment: at least for minor variations on the question, I can see `true` being a reasonable answer. In graphics, you frequently use matrices for transforms. A 3x3 matrix can be converted to a 4x4 matrix that produces the same transform. For some purposes, it's quite reasonable to consider the two equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the language, the different template instantiations are unrelated types. That means that technically, the simplest thing to do is what boost::array does: ignore the problem, the compiler will yell if you try to compare different sizes.

I was inclined to answer that this depends on the domain that you are modeling, but given that the array size is a compile time constant, the user should know that both arrays are different without even trying to compare. Even in templated code, as long as there is a single size parameter everything would fall into place by itself.

Answer (score 5):

It should be a type-error. People that use `boost::array` choose it over `std::vector` because they want evaluation (and failure) at compile-time rather than run-time.

Comment: How would an inline op== that always returns false adversely affect performance?

Comment: @Fred: Not at all, I rephrased the answer.

Comment: How would an inline op== that always returns false not be evaluated at compile-time (assuming a competent compiler)?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: That assumes that it should be an error, which is what this question is about in the first place.  Using the fact that the error can be compile-time to justify that it should be an error in the first place doesn't make sense.  I'm not saying you're wrong that it should be an error, but you don't (currently) have any justification for it one way or the other.

Comment: @Fred: I do not assume that it should be an error. I assume however, that people who choose `array` instead of `vector` *expect* it to be an error.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: You can't know the reasons people choose Fred's class because he hasn't finished deciding its semantics yet!  He's not using boost::array.

Comment: @Fred: Of course I cannot know that. But I can state my reasoning, and then let him decide what he wants to use (and let other users decide whether they concur).

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: If this answer is your reasoning, then it is circular logic; paraphrased: "Fred should decide on a type-error because the people that will use Fred's array will use it because it has a type-error in this case."

Comment: @Fred: Ok, now you're just trolling.

Comment: No, I'm serious.  I may have been too ... dedicated(?) in trying to clear up the apparent misunderstanding.  I still see it that you've said it should be a type-error without providing a good reason why it should be so; just "it should be so because it should be so".

Comment: Sorry, long day. What I mean to say is that other things, such as the size, of an `array` are supposed to be compile-time constants (that is the point of that class), so having comparisons of different sized arrays fail at compile time is in line with that, it's consistent.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Only if all comparisons fail at compile-time (including <, >, etc.).  What it isn't strictly clear that Fred wants these for arrays of differing length, I think just asking this question in the first place is a strong indicator that he does.

Comment: @Fred: I was thinking about this on my way home, and got to the same conclusion. If other comparisons are evaluated at run-time (which they have to, because the values in the array are not compile-time constants), then evaluating this special case at run-time would be inconsistent.

Answer (score 4):

There cannot be a general answer to this question.  It depends on the business logic of the code that is comparing the arrays.

But in general, if I don't know what the business logic is that's comparing the arrays, I'd return `false`.  The arrays are different if they aren't the same size.

Answer (score 1):

If your array does not expose a base class such as `array<int>`, then yield a type error as your class's function is based on strong typing. If you do allow for polymorphism in the size, then return false.

More to the point, what is the benefit of having an operator that in all cases will always return the same value?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is more general than the sole `==` operator.

The `==` operator is intimately tied to `!=`, and possibly tied to `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=`.

The definition should be consistent among all of them, that is either it is possible to compare two arrays of different size (whatever the comparison used) or it is not.

I suspect that both could be useful:

- compile-time error: you're warned that there is something fishy here
- runtime-time false: you don't have to specialize all your template methods to deal with different sizes.

But only one yields a warning during the compilation, the other implies that you hope to discover the issue at runtime (through testing). Therefore I'd provide a "safe" operator overload, and a more verbose method for the "soft" comparison:

```
template <typename T, size_t M, size_t N>
bool soft_equal(array<T,M> const& lhs, array<T,N> const& rhs)
{
  if (M != N) { return false; }
  // comparison logic
}

template <typename T, size_t M>
bool operator==(array<T,M> const& lhs, array<T,M> const& rhs)
{
  return soft_equal(lhs,rhs); // count on the compiler to eliminate the 'if'
}
```

This way, you get the best of both worlds, I think:

- The unwary is warned at compilation
- The compile-time error can be worked around easily if it's intended

**Guideline:** make it easy to get it right, and hard to get it wrong

Answer (score 1):

In C++, `array<int, 3>` and `array<int, 5>` are different types, just as `std::vector<int>` and `std::list<int>` are different types. The fact that they are instantiated from the same template is mostly irrelevant.

Now, you can view both as *sequences* and then comparison would make sense. To do this, however, iterators are commonly used.

Comment: Though they are different types, that doesn't necessarily rule out comparison, even if it is [SCAREy](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=241740#241740).

Comment: @Fred: No it doesn't. But it should be a hint towards not to do it by `operator=()`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays of different sizes are not equal, and in your case you know it at compile-time. Don't implement the equality operator for different sizes; that's pointless! You know that they're not equal already!